# path as param in fat free framework

Tags: php, frameworks, routes, fat-free-framework

while routing in fat free framework, i need a URL as param

but i don't know how.
if i route to

`GET /get-links/@url`

`@url` can be any string WITHOUT `/`.
that means, if i open `/get-links/www.muv.com` it works. but if i open `/get-links/www.muv.com/homepage.html` the routing will not work.

i also tried `GET /get-links/*` - the routing works, meaning my function gets called. 
but then how to get the `@url` (`www.muv.com/homepage.html`)?

and the next problem is: how to enter http://www.muv.com/homepage.html as @url

Answer (score 0):

You may want to escape the characters that give you problems. For URLs there is a standard for this. PHP has [rawurlencode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rawurlencode.php). Maybe this helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this wont's work too. i now changed the routing to GET /get-links without param. means, i made a get param of the url and removed it from the routing. my "new" url is now /get-links?url=http://www.muv.com/homepage.html this works